# PHP Only got month need whole timestamp

Tags: php

I've got a month number from an array and put it in a variable.
Now i want to use the month to make the whole datestamp at the beginning or ending of the month.
But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do that.

```
$startmonth = date("m", strtotime($date[1]));

$endmonth= date("m", strtotime($date[3]));
```

The startdate variable should be something like this: 2015-06-01
The enddate variable should be something like this: 2015-07-30

Comment: `$startmonth = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('Y') . '-' . $date[1] . '-01'));`

Comment: rtfm: http://php.net/date   you only get a month because you're telling php you only want a month. if you want more, then tell php what you want more of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$startmonth = date("Y-m-01", strtotime($date[1]));
$endmonth = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("last day of this month", strtotime($date[3])));
```

First of month is easy: it is always "01" so code that in your format.

Last day of month is harder.  Fortunately PHP's `strtotime` allows for a lot of date manipulations.  See doc at [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

Comment: Thx just what i needed :)